# Why when the BigQuery sink connector v2.5 fails does snapshotting on postgres with Debezium start again?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

When I am trying to do snapshotting of 10 postgresql tables using Debezium and Kafka 3.4 and writing those changes to BigQuery with the confluent BigQuery sink connector v2.5, I sometimes get an error and then snapshotting with Debezium starts again and this repeats each time there is an error. This is annoying, since the issue is with the sink connector and not Debezium. Why does this happen and is there something that one can do about it? My snapshot.mode in the config for the Debezium connector is set to "initial".

I do not know what I can try to solve this problem. It seems the error is random. The only clear error that I could identified so far was for a case where one of the records had an erroneous value in a timestamp column in the source, but in some cases the error is null. There is some problem with the sink connector. I am not sure why snapshotting of the database starts again. I would really appreciate it if someone can help or give me some direction.